# Problem with logging into SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: login, sql-server, sql-server-2005, authentication

I can log into SQL Server Management Studio with a **SQL Server Authentication** login and password, but when trying to log in with **Windows Authentication** I get this error:

"Cannot generate SSPI context. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)"

What is going on here?

Answer (score 2):

See #6 here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/sql_protocols/archive/2006/12/02/understanding-kerberos-and-ntlm-authentication-in-sql-server-connections.aspx

This is a little more complicated:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811889/

But I think either will get you on the right track.

p.s. This might be better posted on ServerFault...